# `env:Client` SOAP Fault with fault string `Internal Error (from client)` on Savon 2.0 SOAP request with correct params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, wsdl, savon, savonrb

Using Savon 2.0 to make a SOAP request, I'm getting an `env:Client` fault code with the fault string `Internal Error (from client)`:

```xml
D, [2020-06-09T05:37:51.323537 #8] DEBUG -- : HTTPI TLSv1_2/none POST request to REDACTED (httpclient)
I, [2020-06-09T05:37:51.370053 #8]  INFO -- : SOAP response (status 500)
D, [2020-06-09T05:37:51.370636 #8] DEBUG -- : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <env:Fault>
      <faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Internal Error (from client)</faultstring>
    </env:Fault>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

The request itself is well-formed and contains all the necessary request parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WSDL had a `sequence` element defined, and the SOAP Fault was because the *order* of the parameters in the request was inconsistent with the defined sequence.

https://w3schools.com/xml/el_sequence.asp

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because a wrong soap action url.